# Python 2.7: Why does json.loads not convert my string to a dict correctly?

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I am asking an ElasticSearch database to provide me with a list of indices and their creation dates using Python 2.7 and the Requests package. The idea is to quickly calculate which indices have exceeded the retention policy and need to be put to sleep.

The request works perfectly and the results are exactly what I want. However, when I run the code below, when I try to convert the json result to a dict, the type of theDict is correct but it reports a size of 1, when there should be at least a couple dozen entries. What am I doing wrong? I have a feeling it's something really dumb but I just can't snag it! :)

```
import json
import requests

esEndPoint = "https://localhost:9200"
retrieveString = "/_cat/indices?h=index,creation.date.string&format=json&s=creation.date"

# Gets the current indices and their creation dates

def retrieveIndicesAndDates():
    try:
        theResult = requests.get(esEndPoint+retrieveString)
        print (theResult.content)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to retrieve list of indices with creation dates.")
        print("Error: "+e)
        exit(3)
    return theResult.content

def main():
    theDict = dict(json.loads(retrieveIndicesAndDates()))
    print(type(theDict)) # Reports correct type
    print(len(theDict))  # Always outputs "1" ??
    for index, creationdate in theDict.items():
        print("Index: ",index,", Creation date: ",theDict[index])
    return
```

The json the call returns:

```
[{"index":".kibana","creation.date.string":"2017-09-14T15:01:38.611Z"},{"index":"logstash-2018.07.23","creation.date.string":"2018-07-23T00:00:01.024Z"},{"index":"cwl-2018.07.23","creation.date.string":"2018-07-23T00:00:03.877Z"},{"index":"k8s-testing-internet-2018.07.23","creation.date.string":"2018-07-23T14:19:10.024Z"},{"index":"logstash-2018.07.24","creation.date.string":"2018-07-24T00:00:01.023Z"},{"index":"k8s-testing-internet-2018.07.24","creation.date.string":"2018-07-24T00:00:01.275Z"},{"index":"cwl-2018.07.24","creation.date.string":"2018-07-24T00:00:02.157Z"},{"index":"k8s-testing-internet-2018.07.25","creation.date.string":"2018-07-25T00:00:01.022Z"},{"index":"logstash-2018.07.25","creation.date.string":"2018-07-25T00:00:01.186Z"},{"index":"cwl-2018.07.25","creation.date.string":"2018-07-25T00:00:04.012Z"},{"index":"logstash-2018.07.26","creation.date.string":"2018-07-26T00:00:01.026Z"},{"index":"k8s-testing-internet-2018.07.26","creation.date.string":"2018-07-26T00:00:01.185Z"},{"index":"cwl-2018.07.26","creation.date.string":"2018-07-26T00:00:02.587Z"},{"index":"k8s-testing-internet-2018.07.27","creation.date.string":"2018-07-27T00:00:01.027Z"},{"index":"logstash-2018.07.27","creation.date.string":"2018-07-27T00:00:01.144Z"},{"index":"cwl-2018.07.27","creation.date.string":"2018-07-27T00:00:04.485Z"},{"index":"ctl-2018.07.27","creation.date.string":"2018-07-27T09:02:09.854Z"},{"index":"cfl-2018.07.27","creation.date.string":"2018-07-27T11:12:44.681Z"},{"index":"elb-2018.07.27","creation.date.string":"2018-07-27T11:13:51.340Z"},{"index":"cfl-2018.07.24","creation.date.string":"2018-07-27T11:45:23.697Z"},{"index":"cfl-2018.07.23","creation.date.string":"2018-07-27T11:45:24.646Z"},{"index":"cfl-2018.07.25","creation.date.string":"2018-07-27T11:45:25.700Z"},{"index":"cfl-2018.07.26","creation.date.string":"2018-07-27T11:45:26.341Z"},{"index":"elb-2018.07.24","creation.date.string":"2018-07-27T11:45:27.440Z"},{"index":"elb-2018.07.25","creation.date.string":"2018-07-27T11:45:29.572Z"},{"index":"elb-2018.07.26","creation.date.string":"2018-07-27T11:45:36.170Z"},{"index":"logstash-2018.07.28","creation.date.string":"2018-07-28T00:00:01.023Z"},{"index":"k8s-testing-internet-2018.07.28","creation.date.string":"2018-07-28T00:00:01.316Z"},{"index":"cwl-2018.07.28","creation.date.string":"2018-07-28T00:00:03.945Z"},{"index":"elb-2018.07.28","creation.date.string":"2018-07-28T00:00:53.992Z"},{"index":"ctl-2018.07.28","creation.date.string":"2018-07-28T00:07:19.543Z"},{"index":"k8s-testing-internet-2018.07.29","creation.date.string":"2018-07-29T00:00:01.026Z"},{"index":"logstash-2018.07.29","creation.date.string":"2018-07-29T00:00:01.378Z"},{"index":"cwl-2018.07.29","creation.date.string":"2018-07-29T00:00:04.100Z"},{"index":"elb-2018.07.29","creation.date.string":"2018-07-29T00:00:59.241Z"},{"index":"ctl-2018.07.29","creation.date.string":"2018-07-29T00:06:44.199Z"},{"index":"logstash-2018.07.30","creation.date.string":"2018-07-30T00:00:01.024Z"},{"index":"k8s-testing-internet-2018.07.30","creation.date.string":"2018-07-30T00:00:01.179Z"},{"index":"cwl-2018.07.30","creation.date.string":"2018-07-30T00:00:04.417Z"},{"index":"elb-2018.07.30","creation.date.string":"2018-07-30T00:01:01.442Z"},{"index":"ctl-2018.07.30","creation.date.string":"2018-07-30T00:08:28.936Z"},{"index":"cfl-2018.07.30","creation.date.string":"2018-07-30T06:52:16.739Z"}]
```

Comment: Take the raw json string and paste it here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and check if it is in the format you want it to be in.

Comment: This is probably because the JSON response contains a single array with several elements for each index. Can you try to take the length of that array instead?

Comment: The shown code is useless to help with your problem. From what you describe, the *content* of the reply is faulty. Showing code that fetches this reply from an unknown, inaccessible machine does not help finding an error in the content. Please add the raw reply before, and perhaps also the data after, parsing.

Comment: as a @val said paste the content of json and also check the content of theDict maybe when it's created the initializer can be set wrong value due to json format

Comment: The call above can be sent to any ElasticSearch database and it will respond in the same format. It's a standard API call.

Comment: OK but many people here will not be familiar with ElasticSearch. Please just show the JSON.

Comment: If your JSON really is an object, you don't have to pass the return value of `loads` to `dict`, because it will already *be* a `dict`.

Comment: serbia99: Thank you for the tip! :) That site reports the json I get from ElasticSearch is valid.

Val: The json has just two items, a key (the index name) and the creation date in "mmmm-dd-yyThh:mm:ss.sssZ" format. e.g.:

[{"index":".kibana","creation.date.string":"2017-09-14T15:01:38.611Z"},{"index":"logstash-2018.07.23","creation.date.string":"2018-07-23T00:00:01.024Z"}]

Comment: I have edited the question with the json the database returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is trying to convert a *list of dicts* to a dict:

```
theDict = dict(json.loads(retrieveIndicesAndDates()))
#         ^^^^^                                     ^
```

That would only work for a *dict of lists*. It would be redundant, though.

Just use the reply directly. Each entry is a dict with the appropriate keys:

```
data = json.loads(retrieveIndicesAndDates())
for entry in data:
    print("Index: ", entry["index"], ", Creation date: ", entry["creation.date.string"])
```

---

So what happens when you do convert that `list` to a `dict`? Why is there just one entry?

The `dict` understands three initialisation methods: keywords, mappings and iterables. A `list` fits the last one.

Initialisation from an iterable goes through it and expects key-value iterables as elements. If one were to do it manually, it would look like this:

```
def sequence2dict(sequence):
    map = {}
    for element in sequence:
        key, value = element
        map[key] = value
    return map
```

Notice how each element is unpacked via iteration? In the reply each element is a `dict` with *two* entries. Iteration on that yields the two *keys* but ignores the values.

```
key, value = {"index":".kibana","creation.date.string":"2017-09-14T15:01:38.611Z"}
print(key, '=>', value)  # prints "index => creation.date.string"
```

To the `dict` constructor, every element in the reply has the same key-value pair: `"index"` and `"creation.date.string"`. Since keys in a dict are unique, all elements collapse to the same entry: `{"index": "creation.date.string"}`.

Comment: I knew I was doing something stupid! LOL! This works, thank you! :) I thought I was casting the list returned from json.loads into a dict.

Comment: What result would you expect from casting a list to a dict? Data types are not, in general, interchangeable.

Comment: Casting is how you make data types interchangeable in most sane languages. I don't think Python is an exception to this.

Comment: @JuanJimenez Sequences and mappings are fundamentally *not* interchangeable. You could as well try and cast an integer to a dict.